# Question about correct notation

Tags: notation

Is the following way to define a set correct:

$\{A_p|A_p\in Z_2\&(\forall A_q \in Z_3)(A_p \cap A_q = 0)\}$

or is it better to write it this way:

$\{A_p|A_p\in Z_2\&(\forall A_q \in Z_3) A_p \cap A_q = 0\}$.

Comment: @Bye_World I think it is saying this set is the subset of $Z_{2}$ of elements that only intersect with all elements of $Z_{3}$ at $0$.

Comment: It is the set of all $A_p$ that belong to set $Z_2$ and that are such that for all $A_q$ in $Z_3$ we have $A_p\cap A_q =0$.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with number theory. Just a question about correct notation. A is some object and Z is a set of such objects.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I was just clarifying for the other user what this set is describing.  I'm not sure if you need the last set of parentheses or not, so we should wait for someone with more knowledge to answer.

Comment: OK.  Then I'd write it as $\{A_p|A_p\in Z_2\wedge\left[\forall A_q \in Z_3, A_p \cap A_q = 0\right]\}$, but that's just to make it more readable.  Either of yours is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, you don't need to put the brackets around the equation $A_p \cap A_q = 0$, because predicate symbols like $=$ are taken to have higher precedence than logical operators like $\&$ (because things like $x = (1 \mathrel{\&} a = b)$ are not well-formed in first-order logic, so there is only one meaningful way to read $x =1 \mathrel{\&} a = b$, namely as $(x = 1) \mathrel{\&} (a = b)$). It is not wrong to put the brackets in.